# WiFi not working on Ubuntu 16.04 new installation on Laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, intel-wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Laptop (HP Envy 4 Ultrabook 1028tu, WiFi module is Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230)
But I can't turn on WiFi, so I cannot connect to WiFi networks.
How to fix this error..? Thank you.

Here is my wireless info script result:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 29 Jul 2016 12:18 KST +0900

Booted last: 29 Jul 2016 00:00 KST +0900

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:1894]

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
    DeviceName: Intel WLAN Intel Jackson Peak 1 802.11bgn 2x2 + BT combo Half M
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4062]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c0e Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0781:5580 SanDisk Corp. SDCZ80 Flash Drive
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 062a:4101 Creative Labs Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
iwldvm                233472  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      2622     1  0 12:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.2/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (BGN)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-31-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               18.168.6.1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Seoul (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

wlo1      13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     6A40B68AAA6792A5BDEA010
depends:        mac80211,iwlwifi,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           force_cam:force continuously aware mode (no power saving at all) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     651BF6CBF283F6F817B8F3A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwldvm]
force_cam: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    5.254775] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    5.278280] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[    5.350931] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[    5.350936] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[    5.350938] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[    5.350942] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 BGN, REV=0xC8
[    5.351182] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    5.358943] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[    5.387108] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[    6.047732] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    8.041996] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[    8.046700] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[    8.115609] r8169 0000:01:00.2 eno1: link down
[    8.115672] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Hard blocked. You need to check bios for a wireless setting, or reset bios to defaults. There may be a hardware switch somewhere too.

Comment: Yes take it literally: something hardware (so NOT the OS) is blocking.

Comment: I checked BIOS setting, but nothing is wrong. Secure boot is off, and I can't find other options for Wireless LAN. Windows can connect to wifi now, but ubuntu not.

Answer (score 1):

Self answer: My problem was Wifi hardware module which was turned off, and I cannot turn it on by Fn key.

But I fixed it now: simply click "Load Setup Defaults" in BIOS.